# Links are breaking in meteor easy search

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-easy-search

Im using meteor easy search to search for content in my app. The content that is being searched for has links to redirect to the whole content. Im also using iron-router and when I search and hit on a link. Im getting a strange url

```
https://leaders-notification-tevinthuku.c9users.io/notificationcomments/HAW78SL82NduvhAeh%22%22%7B%22userId%22%3A%22NFMncrtZFxh2dAQac%22%2C%22limit%22%3A10%2C%22skip%22%3A0%2C%22props%22%3A%7B%7D%7D
```

instead of

```
https://leaders-notification-tevinthuku.c9users.io/notificationcomments/HAW78SL82NduvhAeh
```

Please help.

Comment: It appears the url is getting encoded. As far as preventing this I'm not sure how. Although not a direct solution, I personally use Arunoda's https://github.com/meteorhacks/search-source which I switched to after facing errors with easy-search.

Comment: @chackerian. I think Ill switch too